# How to fix "Variable 'image' must be initialized"

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I'm setting up TextRecognition with Firebase, and the "image" variable is giving me a "Variable 'image' must be initialized" error.

I've followed the tutorial and haven't had any issues until now.

```
            val image: FirebaseVisionImage
            try {
                image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(this, result.uri)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }


            val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .onDeviceTextRecognizer
               //This is what's giving me an error \/
            val myResult = detector.processImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { firebaseVisionText ->
                    // Task completed successfully
                    // ...
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    // Task failed with an exception
                    // ...
                }
```

I expect my app to not crash when this runs.

Answer (score 1):

You have two codepaths, one where image is initialized, and another where it is not:

```
        try {
            image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(this, result.uri)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

If your code goes through the second code path where `FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath` throws an exception, your code will continue without image being initialized.  In that situation, the code afterward will fail when it tries to use an uninitalized `image`.

All you have to do is move the code that works with `image` *inside* the `try` block where `image` is known to have a value, not *after* it where it is not certain that `image` has a value.

Comment: Or maybe better don't swallow the exception in the first place.